# how to add space if string only 2 and max is 5?

Tags: asp.net, substring, space

Current I am doing asp.net c#. I use Eval() to get data from data base and i would like to set the length of the data. anyone has any idea how to do it?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"  Text='<%# Eval("USERID").ToString().PadRight(20).Substring(0,5).TrimEnd() +"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ Eval("USERNAME").ToString().PadRight(20).Substring(0,5).TrimEnd() +"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ Eval("USERPOSITION").ToString().PadRight(20).Substring(0,5).TrimEnd()%>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

here is the sample code of how i get the data.
I tried it out its show quite nice but only if my data is more than 5.
the alignment will be ugly if the data is less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in your page code and pass parameters to it: `Text='<%#yourMethod(Eval("USERID")) %>'`. Alternatively concatenate these values to create a new string in your database layer, and add this new string to a new class property. `Text='<%#Eval("newstring")%>`

Comment: i put the function on webform.cs and I call from webform.aspx it throw me an error. extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class. when i change partial to static it throw me must be partial.. what can I do on this>?

Comment: @LstPatrick don't define it as an extension method, but as a normal method

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen because the aspx is come with the cs file. or else what can I do for this?